# How is the resolution of the identity carried out in the eigenbasis of the position operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm currently reading Robert Littlejohn's Physics 221A (Graduate Quantum Mechanics) Notes, and I encountered this in "[Notes 1](https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/notes/hilbert.pdf)"

[image: Excerpt of Notes]

I'm a bit confused about how he "substituted this back into Eq. (99)." I can see that Eq. 99 probably implies something like $ \psi(x) = \langle x\vert \psi \rangle$, but I'm not exactly sure what the ket $|x \rangle$ is supposed to represent. Eq. 98 would seem suggest that it's $\delta(x - x) = \delta(0) = \infty$, but that doesn't quite make sense to me.

Could somebody please clarify the steps in between this final calculation?

Comment: Do not use images for text and equations; use MathJax instead.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wave functions $\psi(x)$ are essentially infinite-dimensional vectors. So to understand what's going on here, let's first consider a finite (let's say) 2-dimensional vector space. Once we understand how that works, everything will carry over nicely into the infinite-dimensional case.

Consider the vector $|\psi\rangle$. We can display it in a certain coordinate system. The usual choice would be $$|e_1\rangle := \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$|e_2\rangle := \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$
These basis vectors have 2 important properties. First, they are orthonormal, meaning
\begin{equation}\langle e_i|e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}\end{equation}
where $\delta_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$ and 0 for $i\neq j$. For example,
$$\langle e_1 | e_1 \rangle =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = 1$$
$$\langle e_1 | e_2 \rangle =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

We can write $|\psi\rangle$ as a linear combination of these basis vectors:
$$|\psi \rangle = \alpha |e_1 \rangle + \beta |e_2 \rangle = \alpha \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+ \beta\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta
\end{pmatrix}$$
Using the fact that the basis vectors are orthonormal, we can obtain the prefactors in the following way:
$$\langle e_1 |\psi \rangle = \alpha \langle e_1|e_1\rangle + \beta \langle e_1|e_2\rangle = \alpha \cdot 1 + \beta \cdot 0 = \alpha$$
and similarly,
$$\langle e_2|\psi\rangle = \beta.$$
Thus,
$$|\psi \rangle = \langle e_1|\psi \rangle \cdot |e_1\rangle + \langle e_2|\psi \rangle \cdot |e_2\rangle = \sum_i \langle e_i|\psi \rangle \cdot |e_i \rangle$$

In two dimensions, $|\psi\rangle$ can only exist in a superposition of two states. The state $|e_1\rangle$ and the state $|e_2\rangle$. (The common example is a particle with spin-up and spin-down.) When you consider a particle in space, you have an infinite number of possible states, because there are an infinite amount of numbers along the $x$-axis. In the infinite-dimensional case, we denote the basis vectors by $|x\rangle$ and the kronecker-delta becomes a delta-function. Thus, the orthonormality relation $\langle e_i|e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ becomes
$$\langle x|x' \rangle = \delta(x-x').$$
Also, sums are now replaced by integrals (which, by definition, extend the notion of "summing" to continuous variables). So the relation $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i \langle e_i|\psi\rangle \cdot |e_i\rangle$ becomes
$$|\psi\rangle = \int dx \langle x |\psi\rangle \cdot |x\rangle$$
Let's multiply this by $\langle x_0|$ which is just another basis vector. With that we get equation (100):
$$\langle x_0 |\psi \rangle = \int dx \: \langle x_0|x\rangle \langle x|\psi\rangle$$
From this, we can now obtain equation (99) in the following way. The wave function is simply defined as
$$\psi(x) := \langle x| \psi\rangle$$
Plugging this into equation (100), along with the orthonormality condition $\langle x_0|x\rangle = \delta(x-x_0)$ immediately gives
$$\psi(x_0) = \int dx\: \delta(x-x_0) \psi(x).$$

In my opinion, the derivation in the book is kind of "backwards". It makes a lot more sense to consider equation (101) as the natural extension of the finite-dimensional case and go from there.

Finally, you wrote $\delta(0) = \infty$. This is not really the correct way to think about the delta-function. The delta-function is not really a function in the usual sense. It is only well-defined when it sits inside an integral. In this case, the defining relations are
$$\int dx \delta(x) = 1$$
$$\int dx f(x) \delta(x-x_0) = f(x_0)$$
for some function $f(x)$. In the same way as
$$\sum_i \delta_{i,0} = 1$$
$$\sum_i \delta_{ij} e_j = e_i$$
In this sense the delta-function is the natural extension of the kronecker-delta into the realm of continuous variables.

Answer (score 2):

The ket $\left | x \right >$ is an eigenstate of the position operator which means it obeys $\hat{x} \left | x \right > = x \left | x \right >$. It is not normalizable which is why you've found $\left < x | x \right > = \infty$ but it doesn't need to be.

To go through the derivation more slowly, you indeed have to substitute $\psi(x) = \left < x | \psi \right >$. Taking just the fourth and first parts of eq 99 gives
\begin{align}
\left < x_0 | \psi \right > &= \int dx \delta(x - x_0) \psi(x) \\
&= \int dx \delta(x - x_0) \left < x | \psi \right >
\end{align}
where the second line makes the substitution. Using eq 98 finally means replacing the delta function with $\left < x_0 | x \right >$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a maybe more mathematically rigorous answer, you're right in thinking that $\langle x|x'\rangle = \delta(x-x')$ does not quite make sense. There are no physically or mathematically sensible states called $|x\rangle$. This is an idealization. However, $\hat{x}$ is a reasonable self adjoint operator, and while it doesn't have any eigenvectors, it still has a resolution of the identity. In particular, pick any reasonable subset $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then for wavefunctions $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, define the projection operator $$P_{E}\psi(x) = 1_E(x)\psi(x)$$
Where $$1_E(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x\in E\\0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
All you're really doing here is throwing away the parts of the wavefunction that are nonzero in $E$ and keeping the rest.
Formally we write $$\int_{E}|x\rangle\langle x| = P_E$$
Notice that $P_{\{x\}} = 0$. This reflects the fact that there is no such thing as a state that is completely localized at $0$. (or for that matter any region with zero size).

You can also see that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x\rangle \langle x | = P_{\mathbb{R}} = I$$
So this is in fact a resolution of the identity. In this language, no strange infinities or distributions appear. However it's still useful to speak in terms of dirac deltas and position "eigenstates" because you can show  (for a  good reason) that the algebra will generally work out the same.